# How to handle disconnect from Google Game Services?

Tags: android

I use Google Game Services for leaderboards. Showing it like this:

```
static public void showLeaderboard(String lid)
{
  if (isLogined() == 1)
  {
    Log.i(TAG, "Showing leaderboard...");
    Intent intent = Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mClient, lid);
    mApp.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
  }
}

static public int isLogined()
{
  if (mClient != null && mClient.isConnected())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

But when I open leaderboards and logout from Google Game Services with Google UI (Action Overflow menu icon -> Settings -> Sign out) I keep having my isLogined() == 1. So, when I call showLeaderboard() second time - game falls with exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not signed in when calling API
```

GoogleApiClient has callbacks for connection but not for disconnection.
How can I handle sing out from GGS with google UI?

Comment: Nitpick: Instead of returning `0` or `1` to signal a failure or success, you should return a `boolean` instead (that's the Java way of doing it, anyway).

Comment: We have several platforms and for common functions use `int` instead of `boolean` (there isn't `boolean` in objc for example) for ease porting.

Comment: (Just saying). Anyway, this code looks fine to me. Are you testing on a physical device? Perhaps should download a sample project that uses Google Play Games and run it yourself... then if the sample project works correctly you can compare it to your current project and try to find the differences that are causing the break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to keep everything synced up you MUST implement `onActivityResult` properly.

This should look something as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {

   // check for "inconsistent state"
   if ( responseCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED && requestCode == <your_request_code_here> )  {  
      // force a disconnect to sync up state, ensuring that mClient reports "not connected"
      mClient.disconnect();
   }
}
```

NOTE: just make sure to replace `<your_request_code_here>` in the code with the request code you used (which is just `1` in your example). You may need to check for multiple request codes if you use achievements as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `try` `catch`ing the `showLeaderbord` method works fine as well by adding `.disconnect` and `.connect`, and then try again in the `catch` body