# Android Realtime Multiplayer (GPGS) - disconnect not detected?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have a realtime 2-player game based on the ButtonClicker sample.
When I turn off WiFi on one of the connected peers, this peer receives callback `onP2PConnected()`.
But the other `Player` doesn't receive any callback at all.

Also, this code

```
for (Participant p:mParticipants) {
    Log.v(TAG, p.getDisplayName()+" status "+p.getStatus());            
}
```

prints status == 2 (status_joined) on both clients after loss of connectivity.

How can I detect disconnects?

Is it possible to reconnect a client? (Sometimes connection is lost just for a few seconds).

**EDIT** Here is an experiment:

1. Disable, then enable WiFi on peer A
2. Peer A can send messages to B, but B doesn't receive them.
3. Press home button
4. This causes `onStop()` and `leaveRoom()` to be called.
5. Peer B receives `onPeerLeft()` and `onPeersDisconnected()`
   callbacks.

It looks like the peers were re-connected after WiFi was re-enabled.

Comment: I think you're going to use onActivityResult() callback [GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesActivityResultCodes.html#RESULT_LEFT_ROOM) or RESULT_NETWORK_FAILURE as these are the response codes that indicate. You may also refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162684/how-to-handle-disconnect-from-google-game-services) for some code snippet.